# Do I need the text "_size" in the my.cnf file for mysql 5.1?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

This is a pretty simple question about setting parameters in the my.cnf file for mysql 5.1.

This page gives me the parameters I can tune: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-parameters.html 
and so I think I would need to write

```
key_buffer_size = 256M
```

But when I open my current my.cnf, it has the line:

```
key_buffer = 16M
```

My question is, do I need "key_buffer_size" or "key_buffer" or does it not matter which I use? And, how would I know if something in the my.cnf is incorrect? Where's the daemon start log file?

I am running ubuntu; I think version 8.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key_buffer` key is deprecated.

The `key_buffer_size` should be used instead.

The old deprecated key existing in the configurations seems to be a bug: [default my.cnf has deprecated option key_buffer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/1362393).

```
$ mysqld --help
```

> [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead

The `key_buffer` keys seems to have been deprecated for a long time. For example, `key_buffer_size` has been in use all the way back as far as [4.1](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs).

The only mention of this deprecation in the MySQL documentation, that I could find, is a reference here in the [5.7 Release Notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-deprecations).

Answer (score 1):

Both MySQL 5.1 and 5.0 server parameter specification says "KEY_BUFFER_SIZE":

[MySQL 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-parameters.html) | [MySQL 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-parameters.html)